# Plotly traces with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

In the attached heatmap, I would like to know what the value is at the same coordinate across facets by showing a hover bubble over the corresponding tile (or tiles if multiple facets). Tableau does a good job of showing data values across charts. Any way plot.ly can do this as well?

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

heat2 <- structure(list(row = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), col = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L,13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L,10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L,11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L,12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L,13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,14L, 15L), height = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 1.6, 0.6, 1.6, 2.8,3.8, 2.6, 4, 4.4, 4.8, 3.8, 2.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 1, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6, 0, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0.6, 1, 3.2, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.6), marker = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), bin = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), coord = c("10:10", "10:11", "10:12","10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "11:10", "11:11", "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", "12:10", "12:11", "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", "13:15", "14:10", "14:11", "14:12", "14:13", "14:14", "14:15", "15:10", "15:11", "15:12", "15:13", "15:14", "15:15", "16:10", "16:11", "16:12", "16:13", "16:14", "16:15", "17:10", "17:11", "17:12", "17:13", "17:14", "17:15", "18:10", "18:11", "18:12", "18:13", "18:14", "18:15", "10:10", "10:11", "10:12", "10:13", "10:14", "10:15", "11:10", "11:11", "11:12", "11:13", "11:14", "11:15", "12:10", "12:11", "12:12", "12:13", "12:14", "12:15", "13:10", "13:11", "13:12", "13:13", "13:14", "13:15", "14:10", "14:11", "14:12", "14:13", "14:14", "14:15", "15:10", "15:11", "15:12", "15:13", "15:14", "15:15", "16:10", "16:11", "16:12", "16:13", "16:14", "16:15", "17:10", "17:11", "17:12", "17:13", "17:14", "17:15", "18:10", "18:11", "18:12", "18:13", "18:14", "18:15")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("row", "col", "height", "marker", "bin", "coord"), row.names = c(NA, -108L))


p <- ggplot(heat2, aes(x=col, y=row, fill=height))+
  geom_tile()+
  geom_point(data = filter(heat2, marker != 0), aes(color = factor(marker)), size = 0.75)+
  facet_grid(.~bin)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into using Shiny? I believe this example should be helpful in doing so: https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-hover-events/

Comment: That looks promising. Not sure I can easily make what I need off of that example.